# font not showing on live site but shows locally

Tags: html, css

been a while since i touched my code... here's what i have

```
@font-face {
    font-family: brandon-grotesque;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;  
    src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/87035b/0000000000000000000132df/27/l?subset_id=2&fvd=n4");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: adobe-garamond-pro;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;  
    src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/a50d69/0000000000000000000130e6/27/l?subset_id=2&fvd=n4");
}
```

displays fine locally, but the moment its in the browser it doesn't show the brandon grotesque font

Comment: does it work if you change the src url to http instead of https?

Comment: the url seems not valid - I don't get an output or `not found`.

Comment: but why would it display locally? and no changing to http didnt fix it :/

Comment: it is working locally because you installed the font on your system. Make sure the url is working in browser (using nav bar). there should be no problem using https. You should avoid using http.

Comment: ive gone to MS word to see if the font shows and it isnt an option. are you sure i have the font installed locally?

Comment: Have you cleared cache in case it was a caching issue?

Comment: or a similar one. you can inspect the element and see the calculated value of font-family.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably that you have not added the domain to your typekit 'Kit settings'- Check these and see if the domain of your life system is placed there.